# CiFAR10 dataset CNN: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, keras, anaconda, conv-neural-network, typeerror

I am trying to train a Convolution Neural Network written in python using the CIFAR10 dataset. One piece of the code is to show some of the training set's image. However, something went wrong with the  `plt.xlabel(class_names[y_train[i]])` code and it returned the error of `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`. I basically use the same code as shown in my class that runs on fashion_mnist dataset, just changing the image size and number of color channel:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(X_train_full, y_train_full), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
# reshape dataset to the format suitable for CNN. The array has 4 dimensions: (number of images,
# width of each image (32), height of each image(32), number of color channels(in this case 3))
X_train_full = X_train_full.reshape((X_train_full.shape[0], 32, 32, 3))
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], 32, 32, 3))

# split the full training data into the training set and the validation set
X_valid, X_train = X_train_full[:10000]/255.0, X_train_full[10000:]/255.0
y_valid, y_train = y_train_full[:10000], y_train_full[10000:]

print("Training set dimensions: ", X_train.shape) # training and test
print("Validate set dimensions: ", X_valid.shape) # validation
print("Training labels dimensions: ", len(y_train))
print("Validate labels dimensions: ", len(y_valid))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(X_test[0])
plt.colorbar()
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()

class_names = ["Airplane", "Automobile", "Bird", "Cat", "Deer", "Dog", "Frog", "Horse", "Ship", "Truck"]

print(y_train.dtype)

print(y_train[:10])

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(X_train[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[y_train[i]])
plt.show()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[40], line 9
      7     plt.grid(False)
      8     plt.imshow(X_train[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
----> 9     plt.xlabel(class_names[y_train[i]])
     10 plt.show()

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I checked the dtype of the y_train and outputed some of the values, they are all scaler. So I have no idea why I would get that error.